# Street Address Cannot Contain more than 0 Lines on Checkout and Customer Registration Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, customer-account, php-7

Magento 2.2.5 shows `Street address cannot contain more than 0 lines` error when a `registered customer` tries to checkout after `login`. Moreover, when a guest customer after placing an order tries to register on the site. It shows the same error.
A sample screenshot is attached..
[image]

Update: 
I have edited the customer_eav_attribute table and edited the multiline_count field from 0 to 4 and the street address error is vanished.. But the error is replaced by another that is `first name is a required field`